# Unity Nothing to import when importing lastest Fabric version

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-fabric

When Importing Fabric .unitypackage 
I get an empty importing window from Unity

The packet seems to be empty.
This is done on a completely new project. Unity version 2017.1.0p5 (Windows)

I cannot post Images yet.

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. I've seen this happen before as a result of how handles Unity packages. Ensure that the Fabric package is named Fabric (1).unitypackage (for example) instead of Fabric.unitypackage. I'd check the name of the package and adjust it to Fabric.unitypackage.

Comment: Confirmed, it does really weird things. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity can have a difficult time when the Package name contains '(1)' or '(X)'.

Manually change the name of the package to remove those fields.